# HttpPostedFileBase isn't appending files

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

when i select images, it previews it, when i select more images, it previews next to them and then i click Upload Images submit button, it only uploads last selected images, not first ones.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        try
        {
            /*Lopp for multiple files*/
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                /*Geting the file name*/
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                /*Saving the file in server folder*/
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                string filepathtosave = "Images/" + filename;
                /*HERE WILL BE YOUR CODE TO SAVE THE FILE DETAIL IN DATA BASE*/
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded successfully.";
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Error while uploading the files.";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

```js
<script>
    var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
    inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

    function previewImages() {
        var fileList = this.files;

        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            $('.preview-area').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" style="height:150px; width:150px; margin:20px" />');
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        }

        //$(inputLocalFont).hide();
        //inputLocalFont = $('<input type="file" class="dimmy" multiple />').appendTo("#filecontainer").get(0);
        //inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);
    }


</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h3>Multiple file upload with asp.net MVCc/MVC3/MVC4/MVC5, C# and HTML5 </h3>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="image-input" value="" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload You Image" title="Uplad" />
    <div style="color: Red; font-size: 14px">@ViewBag.Message</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="preview-area"></div>

}
```

so please help me out..

Comment: I tested this code, it seems to work fine. What is the browser that you are using to test this? What are your expectations? Do you expect to click the Select Files button multiple times to select files, and then upload all these selected files together?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. Yes, I want to do that.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987896/input-type-file-multiple-add-files-sequentially) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844349/how-to-append-files-in-input-type-file-multiple-before-uploading), I think they are related.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. I'll try this.. @YacoubMassad